The sku converts all data to null, generating a 500 Internal Server Error
Well my problem is the following: I am practicing creating a program with restapi of products, users, roles, etc; Everything worked in Postman the Get, Post, Del and Put but when adding a sku only the post gives problems
This part of the code gives me an erro
package com.springboot.curso.decimo_proyecto.validation;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import jakarta.validation.Constraint;
import jakarta.validation.Payload;

@Constraint(validatedBy = IsExistsDbValidation.class)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface IsExistsDb {
    String message() default "ya existe la base de datos";

    Class<?>[] groups() default { };

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };
} 

This validates the sku but it is not activated here the following:
package com.springboot.curso.decimo_proyecto.validation;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.springboot.curso.decimo_proyecto.services.ProductService;

import jakarta.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import jakarta.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

public class IsExistsDbValidation implements ConstraintValidator<IsExistsDb, String>{

    @Autowired
    private ProductService service;

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return !service.existsBySku(value);
    }
}

This already activates the sku and is linked to IsExistsDb to do a complete check
and when running it gives me this error:
2024-11-24T16:48:52.081-06:00  INFO 6240 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-11-24T16:48:52.082-06:00  INFO 6240 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-11-24T16:48:52.084-06:00  INFO 6240 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 2 ms
Hibernate: select p1_0.id from products p1_0 where p1_0.sku=? limit ?
2024-11-24T16:48:52.660-06:00 ERROR 6240 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: jakarta.validation.ValidationException: HV000028: Unexpected exception during isValid call.] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.springboot.curso.decimo_proyecto.services.ProductService.existsBySku(String)" because "this.service" is null       
        at com.springboot.curso.decimo_proyecto.validation.IsExistsDbValidation.isValid(IsExistsDbValidation.java:17) ~[classes/:na]
        at com.springboot.curso.decimo_proyecto.validation.IsExistsDbValidation.isValid(IsExistsDbValidation.java:1) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:180) ~[hibernate-validator-8.0.1.Final.jar:8.0.1.Final]

As you can see, it tells me that the sku value in service is null when it is not.
package com.springboot.curso.decimo_proyecto.services;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import com.springboot.curso.decimo_proyecto.entitys.Product;

import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;

public interface ProductService {
    List<Product> findAll();

    Optional<Product> findById(Long id);

    Product save(Product product);
    
    Optional<Product> delete(Long id);

    Optional<Product> update(Long id, Product product);

    boolean existsBySku(String sku);
}

the only thing I saw was reading libraries


see what you defined in  ProductService , we often call this repository, you used @Autowired ， so  have you ever import corrsponding dependency like spring-boot-jpa?


As you can see, it tells me that the sku value in service is null when it is not. - obviously it is null, otherwise you would not get a NPE. @Autowired works on spring managed components, but your validator is not one. Add @Component, or other annotation, to register your class as a bean (or register it manually).

Hello, I did what they say and it doesn't work, I used @Componet with autowired

and I also have spring-boot-jpa in the pom and it still sends null
